# How to remove packages that are no longer needed on CentOS 5?

Tags: centos, centos5, yum

While installing package I get some additional packages on dependency. But when I remove installed package with yum, the dependency packages are not removed, though I don't need them anymore.

How can I remove them automatically?

Answer (score 6):

package-cleanup in yum-utils will give you a list of packages that are not longer used. It cannot automatically remove them though it would be simple to use the output in a script that did this.

You could also look into a yum plugin called remove-with-leaves. I have never used it so I'm not sure of its compatibility with the version of yum in CentOS 5. Also, people seem to have a lot of problems given the results of a quick google search.

Answer (score 1):

Check out "package-cleanup" in yum-utils (yum install yum-utils).

Answer (score 0):

With newer yum versions ([>= 3.2.28-13 at least](https://skvidal.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/orphaned-dep-cleanup-in-yum/)), and for more than 10 years now (since the end of 2010), you can use `yum autoremove pkg` and it will automatically take care of removing the unused dependencies.